# Can diffusion models be used to denoise images?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm somewhat familiar with diffusion models, in that they're a process to learn some latent variable representation of images. This is done by learning how to undo the effect of progressive Gaussian noise. I am wondering if I could use diffusion models to denoise images? Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can and there are research publications on that [Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11239).

I am very conversant with speech denoising. For the speech denoising based on the improved diffusion probabilistic models presented in  [Improved Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.09672)

I believe the are unlimited potentials to the use of diffusion models for denoising because of their ability to flexibly model any distribution and the formulation of tractable model that can be evaluated analytically.

Answer (score 0):

Denoising images is like a linear inverse problem for images. There have been multiple efforts to solve the related problems such as super-resolution, deblurring, inpainting, and colorization under various amounts of measurement noise using diffusion models.

Research work DDRM - Denoising diffusion Restoration model tackles the same. DDRM outperforms the current leading unsupervised methods on the diverse ImageNet dataset in reconstruction quality, perceptual quality, and runtime. Here is the read https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.11793